# How to enable Allow HTTP traffic / Allow HTTP traffic on Google Compute Engine with terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-compute-engine, terraform-provider-gcp

Is there any other way to enable these rules directly with terraform without having to create a separate firewall rule in GCP and then attaching tags to compute engine

[image]

Currently I am doing this way

```
resource "google_compute_firewall" "allow_http" {
  name    = "allow-http-rule"
  network = "default"
  allow {
    ports    = ["80"]
    protocol = "tcp"
  }
  target_tags = ["allow-http"]
  priority    = 1000

}
```

and then use this tag in

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "app" {
  ...
  tags = ["allow-http"]
}
```

Comment: have you found any solutions? I'm currently struggling with the same problem and I can't find any way to enable those options via terraform

Comment: @MarcoNecci - No unfortunately not, we moved away from this architecture so was not needed. But you can raise this an issue on terraform github repo

Answer (score 4):

The [Argument Reference](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_instance.html) mentions the option tags. You can use it as follows:

```
...
  tags = ["http-server","https-server"]
...
```

In this same way, you can edit these values using: [gcloud compute instances add-tags](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/add-tags) as follows:

To add the tags to an existing VM instance, use this `gcloud` command:

```
gcloud compute instances add-tags [YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME] --tags http-server,https-server
```

To add the tags at the time of the instance creation, include that flag in your statement:

```
gcloud compute instances create [YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME] --tags http-server,https-server
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I actually saw this link mentioned but it just only add tags to the instance it doesn't tick neither these boxes nor create a Firewall rule

Comment: The link to the argument reference is dead (and the edit queue is full).

Answer (score 0):

We need to have both firewall rules (http, https)in our network. we can able to see that tags in default network.

it works for me

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "name" {
 ....
tags = ["http-server","https-server"]
 ....
}
```